# How to set div in coordinates in grid

Tags: javascript

I have got Js code which can make clickable grid. But then I got troubles, if I want to set the coordinates of new div and place it into the the grid on position it should appear, it appears in the end of the grid instead. My goal is to: if I click on some div, it obtains class 'live' and changes color, also div on position (x-1, y-1) where x and y are the coordinates of clicked div should get the same class and color.
Here's my code:

```
var rows = 38;
var cols = 65;
var grid = new Array(rows);

let gg = document.getElementById('board');

var table = document.createElement("table");

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {//
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.setAttribute("id", i + "_" + j);
        cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");
        cell.onclick = cellClickHandler;
        tr.appendChild(cell);

    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

gg.appendChild(table);

function cellClickHandler() {
    var rowcol = this.id.split("_");

    var row = rowcol[0];
    var col = rowcol[1];

    var classes = this.getAttribute("class");
    if(classes.indexOf("live") > -1) {
        this.setAttribute("class", "dead");
        grid[row][col] = 0;

    } else{
        this.setAttribute("class", "live");
        //grid[row][col] = 1;
    }

}

table.addEventListener('click', function(e){

  let nt = e.target.getAttribute("id");

    var nrowcol = nt.split("_");
    var nrow = nrowcol[0];
    var ncol = nrowcol[1];
    console.log(nrowcol);
    cell.setAttribute("id", (nrow-1) + "_" + (ncol-1));
    console.log(cell);
    cell.setAttribute("class", "live");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Maybe someone will neeed it:

```
ro = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[nrowcol[0]-1];
go = ro.getElementsByTagName("td")[nrowcol[1]-1];
go.append(cell);
```